# How to define different fonts for different language using AngularJS i18n?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [Angular-i18n](http://angular-translate.github.io/). My page is like:

```
<div translate="main.logged.message" translate-values="{username: '{{account.login}}'}">
```

I would like to use font-family `Lato` for English and `Microsoft Yahei` for Chinese.

I have tried:

```
:lang(zh) {
    font-family: 'Microsoft Yahei';
}
```

But it is not working. And also checked the Doc: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide. I cannot find the solution.

How to make it?

---

Update:

I found a post http://yukikodesign.com/orangutangy/?p=191, saying:

> Specify English fonts first and then the Chinese fonts in your font list. This makes it so English fonts render with your desired fonts then the Chinese fonts pick up the other characters.

It's like: `font-family: "Lato", "Microsoft Yahei";`

Surprisingly, it works! But it seems not a generic solution. Any better one?

Comment: You could add a class to you body which gives you the language information and style that class using CSS.

Comment: @localghost Yes, seems a solution. angular-i18n defines a cookie `NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY`, specifying the current language. We can add different class based on this value. But there may be some solution better. It is better to be some solution `native`, by `native` I mean some build-in solution of angular-i18n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a variable 'lang' to the rootscope and then set this variable by read your cookie or localstorage or by read the browser setting (whatever way you go). Based on this variable you can add your language class='{{lang}}' to the same element like your ng-app attribute. Then you can change your font based on this class.  If you provide to change the language dynamically by a function using  $translate.use  then change also your varaiable 'lang' on rootscope and write the changes back to your persistence layer like cookie or localstorage.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$translate', '$scope', '$rootScope',
  function($translate, $scope, $rootScope) {

    //better set this in your run function based 
    //on your cookie or localstorage  
    $rootScope.lang = "en";  


    $scope.changeLanguage = function(langKey) {
      $translate.use(langKey);
      $rootScope.lang = langKey;
      //persist to cookie or localstorage here
    };
  }
]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SnDjGceqNosrkwxflvh7?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Here i have included external font style to my Program using AngularJS i18n: You can achieve this easily using css components.

This is my index.html file (I have only included the important parts)

```
    <html ng-app="starter" class="{{lang}}">

   <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
     <h1 class="ng-binding {{lang}}">{{ "hello_message" | translate }}</h1>
   </ion-header-bar>
```

This is my CSS file

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'DL-Araliya..';
src: url('../fonts/DL-Araliya...eot');
src: url('../fonts/DL-Araliya...eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/DL-Araliya...woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/DL-Araliya...ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;}

.si {
        font-family: 'DL-Araliya..';
        font-weight: 100;
        font-style: }
```

Here is my app.js file

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory     bar above the keyboard
  // for form inputs)
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

  // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
  // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
  // a much nicer keyboard experience.
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})

// translations for english language
.config(function($translateProvider){
$translateProvider.translations("en", {
hello_message: "Hello Sri Lanka",
});

// translations for sinhala lanugage
$translateProvider.translations("si", {
hello_message: "wdhqfndajka Y%s ,xld",
})

 // translations for tamil lanugage
 $translateProvider.translations("ti", {
 hello_message: "ஹலோ இலங்கை",
})

// default langugae when the application starts
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en");
 // if the called element is not found this will be set as the default    langugae
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage("en");

})

// controller for button actions
.controller('Ctrl', function($translate, $scope, $rootScope) {

$scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
  // langKey is whether si/ti/en

$rootScope.lang = langKey;
  // console.log("debug " + $rootScope.ti);
 $translate.use(langKey);
 $rootScope.lang=langKey;
 };

});
```